# Bluetooth commands - Whats possible

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth

Hope this forum can help. I'm very new to the bluetooth technology, so I am sorry in advance for my low tech questions.

Bluetooth can be set up with commands, that can control music, volume control ect.

1) If a person buy's a bluetooth remote, what determine which program the bluetooth controls, if the person have more than 2 music apps on his/hers phone? Can the person change the predetermined settings?

2) Can this function be used for other programs/applications like Endomondo, runkeeper ect. for start/stop/pause exercise?

Answer (score 0):

1) F.E: You press volume up button on that bluetooth remote. Your android device will receive a command completely equal that if you press the volume up button in your phone, so the Android operative system will decide what to do with that command. If you have any app music playing when the command is received, the volume will go up.

2) Yes, you can decide on **YOUR** app programatically what to do when you receive any command, you just have to add a listener for those commands. But if the app is not programmed by you, you cant customize the actions for received commands, you just have the ones wich the original programmer of that application decided.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you want to control your music app and want to do the functionality like vol up/ dwn, forward, back, pause, play etc. bluetooth uses its profile called **AVRCP**  whose fullform is **Audio Video Remote Control Protocol**. This profile manages the above said functionality.

However,there is a limitation or you can say mandatory requirement. You cannot just connect two device with AVRCP profile active on them. AVRCP profile only gets active when A2DP or audio profile is used between two device. Just for your info audio profile is used when we listen to songs on our Bluetooth headphone.

So, if you want to use a Bluetooth remote, which is based on AVRCP profile, to control music app and its functionality, I doubt it will work..

**What you can try**
However, there are remotes which are based on HID profile. The examples of these sort of devices you'll see being used at the time of presentation to change the slides. These devices act like a mouse or keyboard. On pressing specific buttons on these device, it sends interrupts similar to our Usb based keyboards or mouse but over bluetooth. You can explore them and see if they are of any help to you.

@ksonly@ks
[Visit to get more info on Bluetooth stack](http://mre4less.com)